# MariaDB max_heap_table_size is dynamically allocated?

Tags: mysql, memory, memory-management, mariadb

When I am creating a MEMORY table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INT, UNIQUE(id)) ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

and I have set: **max_heap_table_size = 1G** (because I want to insert at least 500MB of data to the table), the moment I create table, MySQL/MariaDB pre-allocates 1GB of Memory or is it (as its name suggests) putting an upper limit to the amount of Memory that can be used for the data of that user-created table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max_heap_table_size system variable sets the limit on the maximum size of MEMORY tables.

for more details, see [The MEMORY (HEAP) Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html)

And the same is mentioned in MariaDB Documentation [MariaDB MEMORY Storage Engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/memory-storage-engine/)

Comment: This does not answer my question (I have read the documentation): is the max_heap_table_size memory pre-allocated or not when creating such a table? That's what I want to make sure...

Comment: In Documentation, it is stated that the memory tables are able to grow but they cannot grow beyond max_heap_table_size value. That means memory is allocated dynamically and max_heap_table_size value is a limit on maximum size of table

Comment: I tested it.  I agree.  But...  Since `MEMORY` tables take space in RAM, you should consider _decreasing_ other settings, esp, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` so that you don't end up swapping.